# why is my initial state in vuex store undefined?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Using vuex-typescript and getting inital state undefined all the time. Once i reset state it is working but only when i reset and window refresh. Here is my setup for some simple module:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

import { module } from "./some_module";

let store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    module,

  },
  plugins: [persist({
    namespace: "mainnamespace",
    initialState: {
    },
    expires: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1e3 // 1 week
  })
  ]
});
```

some_module.ts

```
export interface State {
  something: any;
}

const state: State = {
  something: [],
};

export const module = {
namespaced: true,
  getters: {

    getSomethingArray: (state: State) => {

      return state.something;
    },

  },
  mutations: { 

    resetState: (s: State) => {
      const initial = state;
      Object.keys(initial).forEach(key => { s[key] = initial[key]; });
    },
  }
  actions: {///}
}

const { commit, read, dispatch } =
  getStoreAccessors<HistoryState, any>("somemodule");
const mutations = module.mutations;
const getters = module.getters;
const actions = module.actions;
export const getSomeStuffFromHere = read(getters.getSomethingArray);
```

when i run app and `console.log(getSomethingArray(this.$store))` i got `undefined` and when i `console.log(this.$store)` i can see `somemodule nemespace` but its state is not `something: []` but `some __ob__: Observer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wired got it fixed with adding state:

```
export const module = {
namespaced: true,
state: state,
  getters: {

    getSomethingArray: (state: State) => {

      return state.something;
    },

  },
  mutations: { 

    resetState: (s: State) => {
      const initial = state;
      Object.keys(initial).forEach(key => { s[key] = initial[key]; });
    },
  }
  actions: {///}
}
```